# geolocation services takes time to get longitude and latitude

Tags: android

I am developing an app the gets the location of the user and sends it to the database. My problem is the when the user opens the activity the geolocation takes around a minute to get the longitude and latitude. Is there a way of the getting the location instantly

my code

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}

   private void latAndLong(final String modelSelected, final String email, final String likelyProblem){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation(getApplicationContext());
    Location l = geoLocation.getLocation();
    if (l != null){
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double lng = l.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + lat + "\n Lon: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationSender locationSender = new LocationSender(lat, lng, email, modelSelected, likelyProblem);
        sendNetworkRequest(locationSender);
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }else{

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you would use GeoLocation to get a simple latitude and longitude. From what I know GeoLocation is designed to convert addresses to GPS coordinates, or the other way around. It works by making a request to the Google Places servers, so there it will have a network delay, and is also subject to some usage limitations.

The best way to get a location fast would be using `Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);`
 for fetching the initial location.
Any location updates after that would trigger the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method from the `LocationManager`. Writing your custom logic there would help you track further location changes.

The Android Developers website has a great [article describing the best strategies for using the location services](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html). It is probably the most up to date and comprehensive article about using location services on Android, so I would suggest reading this.

Comment: Thanks. I appreaicate